# Python, need help breaking down a variable into a list

Tags: python

My code is meant to find a specific class element on a page labelled "lh-copy truncate silve" and then copy all links within the attribute as well as info into a list. As of right now, the code simply saves the list into a variable instead and I am having issues making the conversion.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
age_sex = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="lh-copy truncate silver"]')

for ii in age_sex:

      link = ii.find_element_by_xpath('.//a').get_attribute('href')

      sex = ii.find_element_by_xpath('.//span').text

      print(link, sex)
```

The code returns the information that I need in variable as opposed to list format.

Edit: The reason why I need it to be a list as opposed to a variable with a variable if I type variable[1], it'll just give me the second letter of the https:// link which is 't". Whereas if it is in list format, list[1] will return to me the full link. It's the only way that I know to be able to divide the block of text in a variable into separate links that can be accessed separately by my script.

Comment: Your distinction between "list" and "variable" is obscure. Why is a list not a variable?

Comment: The reason why I need it to be a list as opposed to a variable with a variable if I type variable[1], it'll just give me the second letter of the https:// link which is 't". Whereas if it is in list format, list[1] will return to me the full link. It's the only way that I know to be able to divide the block of text in a variable into separate links that can be accessed separately by my script.

Comment: The reason why I need it to be a list as opposed to a variable with a variable if I type variable[1], it'll just give me the second letter of the https:// link which is 't". Whereas if it is in list format, list[1] will return to me the full link. It's the only way that I know to be able to divide the block of text in a variable into separate links that can be accessed separately by my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your `for` loop is only printing individual elements. If you want lists of `link`s and `sex`s, this may be helpful:

```
age_sex = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="lh-copy truncate silver"]')

link_list = []
sex_list = []

for ii in age_sex:

      link = ii.find_element_by_xpath('.//a').get_attribute('href')
      link_list.append(link)

      sex = ii.find_element_by_xpath('.//span').text
      sex_list.append(sex)

print(link_list, sex_list)
```

If you want to keep things together (i.e. list of `link` and `sex` pairs), you can have the following:

```
age_sex = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="lh-copy truncate silver"]')

result_list = []

for ii in age_sex:

      link = ii.find_element_by_xpath('.//a').get_attribute('href')

      sex = ii.find_element_by_xpath('.//span').text
      result_list.append([link, sex])

print(result_list)
```

I hope I'm understanding your problem correctly.

Comment: Copied and pasted your code and unfortunately gives a similar result when I  type these commands after, here are my results:

Comment: >>> link[1]
't'
>>> link[2]
't'
>>> link[3]
'p'
>>> sex[1]
'4'
>>>

Comment: Use `link_list[1]` instead, in my 1st example.

Comment: That's what I was doing wrong, thank you so much!!!! It resolved my issue. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
# If your info in the variable are separated by something, a space for example or any specific char, try the following.

new_list = varibale.split(char)
# if it's a space:
new_list = varibale.split(' ')
```

Could you please explain clearer the problem?

Comment: Sure, sorry that my question wasn't detailed.

Comment: As of right now, what my code returns is along these lines:

Comment: https://google.com/users/2204024 45M 
                                                                             https://google.com/users/3089930 31F 
                                                                             https://google.com/users/4415658 47M                                                                                    If I type link[0:3] I expect for all three links to be returned, instead it only returns 'h' 't' 't'